# Unable to send password reset email using Laravel built in mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, email

I have been trying to get emails to send from Laravel for the past day without success. I have been testing locally using homestead and on a live linux server environment with no luck.

I have removed email settings from the .env file. and directly added the settings in my config/mail file.

so far I have tried office 365 settings, gmail and finally maligun, none of which send an email.

my settings are below.

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'postmaster@sandbox********099b827475b585029.mailgun.org'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Test account'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('postmaster@sandbox****************099b827475b585029.mailgun.org'),
'password' => env('********************'),
```

I complete the password reset process via password/reset and it says the password reset link was sent successfully but it is never sent, the mailgun logs confirm no email was sent, the token is updated in the password_reset table

I ssh'd onto homestead and tested sending a email via mailgun using curl and this works.

if I set mail driver to SMTP I still get the same issue.

when setting the drive to 'log' the log files shows the email template etc.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What environment you working with? Local or production?

What kind of email you're using? Gmail or testing mail such as mailtrap?

If gmail did you active smtp from settings? Please provide more information.

Update:

let us test other ways to see if it makes any differences:

Go to your routes file `web.php` and comment this:

```
// Auth::routes();
```

Now add following routes:

```
// Authentication routes
Route::get('/login',['as'=>'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
      Route::post('/login', ['uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@login']);
      Route::get('/logout',['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
      Route::get('/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegisterForm']);
      Route::post('password/email', ['as'=>'password.email', 'uses'=>'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
      Route::get('password/reset', ['as'=>'password.request', 'uses'=>'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
      Route::post('password/reset', ['as'=>'password.request', 'uses'=>'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
      Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as'=>'password.reset', 'uses'=>'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
      Route::post('logout', ['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
```

Try and see if it works or not.

Comment: I have tried, Gmail using thew smtp driver, office 365 using the smtp driver, maligun using the malign driver. I have tired both local and production.

Comment: @Darkskies16 are you using custom route for authentication?

Comment: try this `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` in your `.env` file.

Comment: standard routes for auth. I have just tried mail_encryption=ssl, it made no change. the using the password/reset route it says the password reset link has been sent but an email is never received. I have proven it's not a firewall/port issue but using curl to send an email using malign setting

Comment: @Darkskies16 I updated my answer try it and let me know.

Comment: Do you have this trait in your user model: `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` ?

Comment: yes, I also tried a fresh install of larval last night on a new homestead box and the reset password email doesn't work there either, could it be a larval bug?

Comment: No it's not laravel bug, try use mailtrap and please load your info from env file instead of mail config file. I think it's from your provider (not sure yet)

Comment: so I replaces username and password in the mail config to mail_username and mail_password, and added the smtp username and password to the env file and it now works!

Comment: @Darkskies16 i didn't follow, is it works now or that was a question?

Comment: yes it works, after I did the above. thanks for all your help

Comment: @darkskies glad to hear that, please accept my answer, don't forget vote up ;)